# Regular expression for sequences of word characters enclosed in braces

Tags: regex

I have an input string containing some words (as in `\w+`) all enclosed by curly braces. I need to capture the individual words with a regular expression.

For example, from this input:

```
{abc 123... 456!}
```

I need to capture the following strings:

```
"abc", "123", "456"
```

So far, I have been able to capture words using the pattern `/(\w+)\W*/` when the words **are not** enclosed by curly braces. But all my attempts to develop the pattern further to support the outer curly braces have failed.

Comment: What is the regex flavor? In PCRE/Onigmo/Boost, you can use `(?:\G(?!^)|\{(?=[^{}]*}))[^{}\w]*\K\w+` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/BXEkXG/1)).

Comment: Uhm, do word boundaries `\b` work in your regex flavor? `\b\w+\b`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That will work for me under RE2. Thanks for the demo link.

Comment: @LukStorms Word boundaries are new to me, thank you for the info. I would like to use `\b\w+\b` in my solution because it looks simpler than other solutions, but I have not discovered how to make it work for the specific case given in my example.

Comment: RE2  does not support `\G` and lookarounds. There is no solution for RE2.

Comment: Well, could still capture either stuff between brackets or words. `\{.*?\}|\b\w+\b` Then get rid of the stuff with brackets.

Answer (score 0):

What programming language are you using?
We could apply regex twice:

```
\{[^{}]+\}
```

will return the contents of the curly braces
and then

```
[^{] ]+
```

will return the individual values